# Creating a slideshow from MathKernel

Tags: front-end, notebooks, mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink, slideshows

I've recently started playing with the MathKernel using Wolfram.NETLink.dll and it works great in my C# .NET solution.

To give some background, I had created a Mathematica notebook that generates some pretty fancy listplots all stored prettily in a slideshow. However, my experience with Mathematica's slideshow functions are mostly through the Slideshow Palette (which begs the question can I access the Slideshow Palette through MathKernel).

Is there another way to do all the slideshow functions stored on the Slideshow Palette through the MathKernel?

Is it possible to create my own custom functions that would be accessible through the MathKernel?

Are there other options to use in this case?

Comment: There are two things: 1. Controlling the Mathematica kernel from .NET/C#.  It seems you got this working. I cannot help with this, as I don't know C#.  2. Controlling the front end from the kernel (which is being controlled from C#—but that is mostly separate thing here).  FrontEnd programming is sometimes not so trivial.  You may not realize it, but what you describe in the question is just too broad to address.  I suggest you start by reading a bit [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookProgramming.html), ...

Comment: ... then formulate concrete questions about very specific FrontEnd related tasks.  You can minimize the .NET part of the question, and just make it clear that you are using Mma from .NET. There are certain FrontEnd related things that need workarounds when done from a *controlled* kernel (as opposed to an interactively used kernel).

Comment: @Szabolcs wow thanks! I appreciate any path forward. If I find something more specific that I need help on, I'll edit this question with a more specific question.